# SendEmail Message Action when clicked on Edit throwing Object reference not set to an instance

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

SendEmail Message Action when clicked on Edit throwing Object reference not set to an instance. Below is the error.

```c#
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.Dialogs.SendMailEditor.FillContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, String allowedTypes, Edit insertValueTo, GenericControl link, Image img, Literal label) +301
   Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.Dialogs.SendMailEditor.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +448

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +211
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Ob`enter code here`ject[] parameters) +35
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +337
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71

System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Which version of WFFM?

Comment: Are you using the default SendEmail SaveAction or is this a custom one? Have you made any changes to the SendEmailEditor and referenced in your custom SaveAction if using one?

Comment: Going by where you're seeing the error I'm guessing you may have an issue with a custom field that you have added to the form

Comment: Sitecore 7.2 and WFFM 2.4 version. This is happening when I try to edit the SendEmailMessage action after I add this action to form in the Form Designer. No this is not a custom action it is out of the box functionality.

Comment: if you can, share the raw content of your 'save actions' field